# Replace consecutive white spaces between words with one hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

The question is from freecodecamp [Link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/functional-programming/apply-functional-programming-to-convert-strings-to-url-slugs)

> Fill in the `urlSlug` function so it converts a string `title` and returns the hyphenated version for the URL. You can use any of the methods covered in this section, and don't use `replace`. Here are the requirements:
>
> The input is a string with spaces and title-cased words
>
> The output is a string with the spaces between words replaced by a
>   hyphen (`-`)
>
> The output should be all lower-cased letters
>
> The output should not have any spaces

```
// the global variable
var globalTitle = " Winter Is  Coming";


function urlSlug(title) {
let toArr = title.split("");
let newArr = toArr.map(a=> {
    if(a==" "){
        a= "-";
    }


    return a.toLowerCase();
} );

if(newArr[0] == "-"){
    newArr.splice(0,1);
}


let finalArr = newArr.join("");
return finalArr;

}
// Add your code above this line

var winterComing = urlSlug(globalTitle); // Should be "winter-is-coming"
console.log(urlSlug(globalTitle));
```

Right now I have not been able to solve how I could get rid of the extra hyphen from the output.

I'm not supposed to use `replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do this easily using `trim()` and a simple regex:

```js
var globalTitle = "  Winter       Is  Coming Now    ";
var slug = globalTitle.trim().replace(/[ ]+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
console.log(slug);
```

`[ ]+` ensures that any number of spaces (1 or more) gets replaced with a minus sign once.

If for some reason you can't use replace, you could use `Array.filter()` like so:

```js
var title = "       Winter     Is Coming     Now     ";
var slug = title.split(" ").filter(word => word.length > 0).join("-").toLowerCase();
console.log(slug);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on it till now , Haven't looked at the answers. 
But I solved it this way. Might be inefficient.

```
// the global variable
var globalTitle = "Winter Is Coming";
function urlSlug(title) {
let toArr = title.split("");
let newArr = toArr.map(a=> {
    if(a==" "){
        a= "-";
    }


    return a.toLowerCase();
} );
if(newArr[0] == "-"){
    newArr.splice(0,1);
}

for(let i=0;i<newArr.length;i++){
    if(newArr[i-1]=="-"&& newArr[i]=="-")
    {
        newArr.splice(i,1,"");
    }
}
let finalArr = newArr.join("");
return finalArr;

}

var winterComing = urlSlug(globalTitle); // Should be "winter-is-coming"
console.log(urlSlug(globalTitle));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to continue your thought of `split()` and then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce the elements of the array to a single output:

```js
var globalTitle = " Winter Is  Coming";

function urlSlug(title) {
    let split = title.split(' ');

    return split.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
        if (currentValue.length > 0) {
            accumulator += currentValue.toLowerCase();
            accumulator += (index < split.length - 1) ? '-' : '';
        }

        return accumulator;
    });
}

console.log(urlSlug(globalTitle));
```